# jquery add tag around unnested text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

This is a really hard question to find a title for, but here is it.

I got this HTML, that I can't change

```
<ul>
    <li>
        First part of the list
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Second part of the list
        <ul>
            <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I'd like to apply things to the "first part of the list" and "Second part of the list" part, **but not the nested ul part**, like CSS transform scaleY, and a custom Jquery onClick method.

So, the solution I'd like would be a way to JQueryly add  around those.

Is this possible?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can `filter()` the `li` `contents()` to retrieve the text nodes within it, then wrap that in a `span` and apply the needed CSS rules. Something like this:

```js
$('#container > ul > li').each(function() {
  var foo = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent
  }).wrap('<span />');
});
```

```css
#container > ul > li > span {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scaleY(2);
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      First part of the list
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Second part of the list
      <ul>
        <li>item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```